# PHP: Как узнать изменяется ли файл?

Tags: php, файлы, php7, файловая-система, file-get-contents

Скрипт при определённом условии получает файл с помощью file_get_contents, изменяет его и загружает обратно с помощью file_put_contents. Всё ок, файл изменяется, но если условие не правдиво и изменение файла не должно происходить - файл уже изменился. Если загрузить это на хостинг и зайти с двух разных компов, измениться ли файл на сервере или сохранится просто в кеше?

Comment: суть проблемы не ясна. Если условие не правдиво  то и записывать это дело не надо.

Comment: Допустим условие правдиво у одного, а у другого нет. Если файл изменится на другом компе, изменится ли он на сервере?

Comment: смотря как реализуешь, всё в твоих руках.